# ggalluvial: How to order the lines between blocks to be in same order as your data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, stream, ggalluvial

I have made an alluvia plot using the `ggalluvial` package in R. I am trying to order the flows (lines between blocks) so that they are much easier to read - I am aiming for them to be stacked on top of each other (orange color, followed by purple color) in each section for each block. Here I am defining a block to be the vertical bars that sit on the x-axis in positions 1, 2, and 3. Additionally, it is placing the text in inappropriate places within each block.

**Reproducible Example**

#Making the data.frame

```
w <- c("Rain Forest", "Desert", "Arctic", "City", "Low Earth", "Boonies", "Space")
x <- 1:40
y <- c("Bird", "Tiger", "Cat", "Parrot", "T-Rex", "Dreadwing")

set.seed(0)
GenComp <- data.frame(
  Location = sample(w, size = 28, replace = TRUE),
  Frequency = sample(x = x, size = 28, replace = TRUE),
  Animal = sample(x = y, size = 28, replace = TRUE),
  Gender = rep(c("Male", "Female"), 14))

GenComp <- GenComp[order(GenComp$Gender, GenComp$Animal, GenComp$Location, decreasing = FALSE),]
row.names(GenComp) <- 1:nrow(GenComp)

GenComp$Location <- factor(GenComp$Location, levels = sort(unique(GenComp$Location)))
GenComp$Gender <- factor(GenComp$Gender, levels = c("Female", "Male"))
GenComp$Animal <- factor(GenComp$Animal, levels = sort(unique(GenComp$Animal)))
GenComp <- GenComp[, c(4, 3, 1, 2)]
```

#Graphing

```
library(ggalluvial)
ggplot(GenComp,aes(y = Frequency,
                            axis1 = Gender, axis2 = Animal, axis3 = Location)) + 
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Gender), width = 1/8, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 0.25, width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), reverse = TRUE, size = 3)  +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Fauna") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Female = "#691869", Male = "#EBBC55")) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

Here is the graph:
[image: Alluvia_FlowLines]

The red arrows point to the text that is being written where they are not supposed to be. The blue circles are an example of what I don't want - circles show a mix of yellow and purple lines. I would like to always keep the yellow lines on top and purple under the yellow for each section of each block.

Trying to make sense of things, I learned in this post [Ordering of streams within each block](https://github.com/corybrunson/ggalluvial/issues/3) that 'the order of the streams in `alluvial()`is controlled by the row order. This is why I have ordered the `GenComp` data.frame in the order I would like to see the `alluvia` graph `GenComp <- GenComp[order(GenComp$Gender, GenComp$Animal,GenComp$Location, decreasing = FALSE),] ; row.names(GenComp) <- 1:nrow(GenComp)`.

However, in the `ggplot2` version, even if I reorder the rows, I get the same plot. A work around was the implementation of the commands `lode_favor` and `lode_order`.

If this is the answer, how can I implement these commands with `ggalluvia` in the code above?

I also learned here: [ggalluvial - let order of stratums follow dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69507226/ggalluvial-let-order-of-stratums-follow-dataset) that "you can re-order the axes by converting your character vectors to factors and specifying the levels you want." Which is why I have the `factor(..., levels = ())` specified in the above code. This also did not work.

I read here: [The Order of the Rectangles](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggalluvial/vignettes/order-rectangles.html) under the section: "Manual lode ordering" that "we can pass a vector that puts the cases in the order of their IDs in the data at every axis" and the vector can be passed in the `stat_alluvium()` command. However, adding the following commands to the code above (assigning the order: `lode_ord <- 1:28`and adding `stat_alluvium(aes(order = lode_ord))` into the code above made a horrific mess of the graph - it inserted gray lines, reduced the color of the flows ... just horrid.

Any ideas on what I can do to 1) fix the text issue and 2) organize the lines in such a way that the yellow lines always stack on top of the purple lines for each section in each block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `lode.guidance = "forward"`:

```
ggplot(GenComp,aes(y = Frequency,
                            axis1 = Gender, axis2 = Animal, axis3 = Location)) + 
  geom_alluvium(lode.guidance = "forward", aes(fill = Gender), width = 1/8, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_stratum(alpha = 0.25, width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)), reverse = TRUE, size = 3)  +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Fauna") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Female = "#691869", Male = "#EBBC55")) +
  guides(fill = "none")
```

[image: Alluvial plot of animals]

Comment: Thank-you very much for that. That worked perfectly! I was using that flag in an incorrect place when I was originally testing it (before I posted). 

May I ask you if you also have a suggestion for why the text is being placed in the incorrect boxes? For example, the visual you posted (on x-axis = 3) shows "Boonies" In a seemingly random place and an empty box above "Space" - that should be 'Rain Forest." -Thank-you.

Comment: Just figured out the text issue. Putting `geom_stratum(reverse = TRUE)` fixed the issue!